# Unique foreign key in rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

In migrations file, I'm adding foreign key using below syntax.

```
class CreatePreferences < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :preferences do |t|
      t.integer :user_id, null: false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :preferences, :users, column: :user_id, dependent: :destroy, :unique => true
  end
end
```

But `:unique => true` is not working.

```
mysql> show indexes from preferences;
+-------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table       | Non_unique | Key_name            | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| preferences |          0 | PRIMARY             |            1 | id           | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| preferences |          1 | fk_rails_87f1c9c7bd |            1 | user_id      | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

What is the right way to add a unique foreign key using migrations?

I could've added uniqueness validations in the model itself. But it won't be foolproof if I have multiple workers running. ([Reference](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations))
[image]

Comment: I guess you should add index to make it unique in the DB level

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
class CreatePreferences < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :preferences do |t|
      t.integer :user_id, null: false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :preferences, :users, column: :user_id, dependent: :destroy, :unique => true
    add_index :preferences, :user_id, unique: true
  end
end
```

Comment: Do I need to have `unique` in both `add_foreign_key` and `add_index` ?

Comment: `foreign_key` and `index` are different things, so I think you can have both `unique`

Comment: As of Rails 5.2, `unique` is not a valid option for [`add_foreign_key()`](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_foreign_key), and is silently ignored. It is however a valid option for [`add_index()`](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_index).

Answer (score 47):

In Rails 5 you can accomplish the same with the more elegant:

```
t.belongs_to :user, foreign_key: true, index: { unique: true }
```

This will generate a foreign key constraint as well as a unique index. Don't forget to add `null: false` if this is a required association (sounds like it in the case of the original question).

Note that `belongs_to` is just an alias for `references`.